# Why primitive arrays are not allowed to add to a JSON structure in GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to do this to create a json object like below.

```
JsonObject      request             = new JsonObject();
request.addProperty("requestid", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
request.addProperty("type", "hotel");
request.addProperty("markups", new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0}); // This says "The method addProperty(String, String) in the type JsonObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, double[])"
request.add("markups", new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0});// This says "The method add(String, JsonElement) in the type JsonObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, double[])"
```

JSON object :

```
{
  "requestid": "05afcd81-9c59-4a21-a61e-ae48fda6bdd0",
  "type": "hotel",
  "markups": [1.0,2.0,3.0]
}
```

Please note that this is not about, fromJson and toJson thing. It is JSON CREATION and READING objects NOT a CONVERSION.
So, how can I do it with the above implementation.

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking. Its obvious Gson's `JsonObject` doesn't have the methods you're trying to use. I'm guessing you need to read the docs and look at `JsonArray`

Comment: That is true Brain. I've tried about the JsonArrays too. But it allows to add only the JSONElements right? But I want a way to add an array of primitives. I mean if we can do it when we are just converting. Then Why it is not allowed when it is creating?

Comment: *"Why it is not allowed when it is creating?"*  - Ask the author!

Comment: I just asked it to pretend that there should be a way for it.I don't think he will answer this in this forum. :) Anyway he shouldn't I think. Because he has given a way for it. Actually more than one. Please check the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using JsonPrimitive as follows:

```
JsonObject      request             = new JsonObject();
request.addProperty("requestid", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
request.addProperty("type", "hotel");

JsonArray       jpArray         = new JsonArray();
jpArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(1.0));
jpArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(2.0));
jpArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(3.0));

request.add("markups", jpArray);
```

OutPut :

```
{
  "requestid": "6259f169-3a55-4a2e-b03c-5931d4daf2fd",
  "type": "hotel",
  "markups": [
    1.0,
    2.0,
    3.0
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to use the parse tree object to build your JSON structure, you either need to instantiate and add the values to a `JsonArray` object, or use Gson and convert your `double[]`. I'm assuming you'd rather do the latter:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    double[] d = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0};
    JsonElement e = new Gson().toJsonTree(d);
    JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
    o.add("array", e);
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Output:

> {"array":[1.0,2.0]}

The `toJsonTree()` method takes your Java array and converts it to the Gson parse tree `JsonArray` and returns it as the the superclass `JsonElement`

Comment: Thank you Brian. Nice one!. I found another way too with JsonPrimitives.